# .htaccess in Notepad ++

Tags: .htaccess, notepad++

I am working with Notepad and the FTP plugin.  The .htaccess files do not show up in the folder tree of the server.  Anyone else encountered this and know of a fix?

Comment: By any chance are you ftping it to a shared samba drive or the local drive or you cannot see it in remote folder to begin with?

Comment: Also what user are you logging into the server for the ftp access and do you have execute bits set on the directory?

Comment: files starting with a dot can be a pain to windows based tools...

Comment: not sure... i can see it  with other ftp programs like Filezilla, I was just hoping to be able to edit it live with Notepad but I guess that is not such a great idea..

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I know this is an old question now, but I've run into this problem, too.

In the current version of Notepad++ (v5.9) the NppFTP plug-in (v0.23) has a setting for each connection called "LIST parameters". It is accessible via `Settings/Profile settings/FTP Misc`. Enter "-al" there and hidden files should be visible. Remember to set it for each profile.

Comment: And remember to disconnect and connect again in order to function

Answer (score 0):

The file is there, its just hidden.  If you can type in a file name for download you can probably get it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use notepad plus but if the ftp plugin has a setting to show hidden files then you should be able to change that so you can see the .htaccess file. The server is probably unix so any file that starts with a dot is a hidden file.

Comment: I can not find an option to show hidden files in Notepad++ .. weird ... seems like there should be one

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behaviour. In options of your FTP client plugin find option "show hidden and hidden files. For example in Total Commander it's:

> Network -> FTP Show hidden files

Answer (score 0):

In the FTP page profile settings, choose `FTP misc.` and type `-al`. It fixed my problem